# Why does "all to the mustard" mean excellent?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

While reading P.G. Wodehouse's *The Inimitable Jeeves* I came across a fascinating expression of "all to the mustard!" It is defined as meaning excellent. Why? Can anyone please help me understand this expression?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/72476/14666

Comment: See: http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/2/messages/198.html http://www.bigsiteofamazingfacts.com/where-does-the-expression-to-cut-the-mustard-come-from-and-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kris' link](http://www.bigsiteofamazingfacts.com/where-does-the-expression-to-cut-the-mustard-come-from-and-what-does-it-mean/) offers this explanation:

> [During] the beginning of the century, “to be the proper mustard” was a slang phrase meaning to be the genuine article, possibly because some so-called “mustard” of that period would not pass today’s pure food requirements.
>
> From that, immediately, came “all to the mustard,” that is, all one could ask for, fine and dandy, “copesetic,” as the late Bill Robinson would say.